# Replace each instance of jinja variable with string in Python

Tags: python, jinja2

I have the following code to create a string using Jinja

```
from jinja2 import Template

jT = Template('"text": {{text}}, "peripherals": {{peripherals}}')
params = {'text': 'some_text', 'peripherals': 'mouse'}
jT.render(**params)
```

The resulting output is:

`'"text": some_text, "peripherals": mouse'`

Is there a way to surround the substituted values inside quotes, like so:

`'"text": "hello", "peripherals": "mouse"'`

Besides editing the existing jinja and using {{text|tojson}}, is there a way/function in Python to automatically wrap every substituted value inside quotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the Jinja package doesn't have a built-in tool to replace each variable automatically with strings, then I think this would be the right approach:

```
import re
from jinja2 import Template

template = '{"text": {{text}}, "peripherals": {{peripherals}}}'
# Use regular expressions to identify the variables
template = re.sub(r"({{)(\w*)(}})", r'"\1\2\3"', template)

jT = Template(template)

params = {'text': 'some_text', 'peripherals': 'mouse'}
print(jT.render(**params))
```

It simply searches for the variables in the template and encapsulates them inside quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Just modify your template:

```
from jinja2 import Template

jT = Template('"text": "{{text}}", "peripherals": "{{peripherals}}"')
params = {'text': 'some_text', 'peripherals': 'mouse'}
print(jT.render(**params))
```

Returns:

```
"text": "some_text", "peripherals": "mouse"
```

Without modifying the template, use this custom code:

```
jT = Template('"text": {{text}}, "peripherals": {{peripherals}}')
params = {'text': 'some_text', 'peripherals': 'mouse'}
j = jT.render(**params)
# Specifically for your example:
print(f'{j.split()[0]} "{j.split()[1][:-1]}", {j.split()[2]} "{j.split()[3]}"')
# More general:
for i in range(len(j.split()) - 1):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        print(j.split()[i] + ' ', end='')
    else:
        print('"' + j.split()[i][:-1] + '",', end=' ')
print('"' + j.split()[-1] + '"')
```

Returns:

```
"text": "some_text", "peripherals": "mouse"
"text": "some_text", "peripherals": "mouse"
```

Put it in a function if you need to run it for multiple templates:

```
def render_template(j):
    for i in range(len(j.split()) - 1):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            print(j.split()[i] + ' ', end='')
        else:
            print('"' + j.split()[i][:-1] + '",', end=' ')
    print('"' + j.split()[-1] + '"')


render_template(j)
```

Again returns:

```
"text": "some_text", "peripherals": "mouse"
```

Comment: Actually, I can't modify the template, I can only substitute the variables using the params dictionary and render them

Comment: I have posted my answer. If I have to use custom code, I think regular expressions are the way to go :)

Comment: That does look simpler, yes.

Comment: if you like my answer, you could upvote it, and then I can accept that answer and mark it as Solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

you could add the quotes inside your params.

```
params = {'text': '"some_text"', 'peripherals': '"mouse"'}
```